# Adobe Flash CS6 Error 1172 Definition Could Not Be Found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, gsap

The error specifically states that "Error 1172: Definition com.greensock.TweenMax could not be found."

I decided to got to Edit > Preferences > ActionScript and clicked on ActionScript 3.0 settings since I am using TweenMax in Actionscript 3.0. I located the path for the com folder in the Library, Source, and External Library paths just to be sure it was identified by Flash. It even does that auto selection feature that Adobe has when I type in "import com.greensock.TweenMax." It can't be where I typed it, because it's typed in with the other imports that work correctly. So I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm pretty new with Flash, so I apologize if I listed my problem and didn't realize it.

Comment: You should answer your own question with that fix so it's crystal clear to others that it's a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so for reference sake for others. I fixed this easily. What I did was link to originally:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\Third-Party\com
```

I did this to access the com folder that included "**com.greensock.TweenMax**"

Here is what is correct:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\Third-Party\greensock-v12-as3
```

Inside this **greensock-v12-as3** folder is the **.\com\greensock\TweenMax.as**

Apparently you need to select the parent folder of whatever you are importing instead of the folder.

Comment: That's why you should EXTRACT the library withing your src folder, not just unzip the whole file anywhere... The normal path should be the `src` folder, and there should be `com` folder inside, with `greensock`, etc.. Don't just add paths, as you'll get in the deep ****